# All, any and some function in BIG QUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

Good evening everyone!

I need to use the following expression in big query:

```sql
select
*
from employee
where age > all (
    select
        age
    from employee
    where gender = 'M')
```

but for some reason I cannot use this estructure, with the following error "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword ALL at [5:13]".

I can use it in sqlserver, but how can I make it works in BQ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider also below approach

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM employee
QUALIFY age > MAX(IF(gender = 'M', age, NULL)) OVER()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below query in BigQuery.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM employee
 WHERE age > (SELECT MAX(age) FROM employee WHERE gender = 'M');
```